# ASP.NET web API - System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have an asp.net web API. (net framework 4.6.1) I am calling a 3rd party rest API (Product) in one of my actions. In functional tests, everything works as expected, no problem. But when I do spike tests (let's say, 100 users, 10 seconds ramp-up time) I am getting `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled error` after some successful responses. I googled and came across that it might be due to timeout. I added `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);` but still getting the same error.

Here is how I call this 3rd party API. Is there any problem with an async call? Would you please have a look at my code?

```
public class UtilitiesTest
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();


       //some not relevant code here

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallRazer(GameRequest gameRequest, string url)
        {
            try
            {
                FormUrlEncodedContent content = null;

                if (url == "Product/")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //some code here


                        //Timeout
                        _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600);
                        //Call Game
                        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://test.com/" + url, content);
                        return response;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        content.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //some code here

                        //Call Game
                        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://test.com/" + url, content);
                        return response;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        content.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }


    }
```

and here is how I call Razer:

```
private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallProducts()
        {
            //some code here

            #region Call Razer for products


            //**Call Razer**
            var response = await Utilities.CallRazer(products, "Product/");

            var htmlResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductResponseDto>(htmlResponse);

           // some code here

            return response;
        }
```

Somebody in another forum, suggested me to use HTTPWeb Request instead of Httpclient. So I changed my code like below and all my troubles are gone.

```
//HTTPWebRequest
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://test.com" + url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";

var keyValueContent = productRequest.ToKeyValue();
var formUrlEncodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValueContent);
var urlEncodedString = await formUrlEncodedContent.ReadAsStringAsync();

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(await request.GetRequestStreamAsync()))
{
     streamWriter.Write(urlEncodedString);
}

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) (await request.GetResponseAsync());

response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
     StatusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode,
     Content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()),
};

return response;
```

Comment: Task cancellation is due to the Cancellation Token passed, My understanding is if you are not explicitly passing then Cancellation token is attached in 3rd party API, which can trigger a task cancellation for variety of logical reasons. Check [Task Status Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Also check [Task Cacellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation?view=netframework-4.8), this is not same Task faulting due to exception, and [Cancelling Async task after Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time)

Comment: I am not passing a cancellation token. This happens when I spike test this method. At first, I get successful responses but after some time I get errors.

Comment: but 3rd party API may check that first, otherwise Task would have faulted not cancelled

Comment: @MrinalKamboj thank you, I will check the 3rd party. How about my code by the way? Any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's still timing out after 600 seconds, then your web service just can't keep up.

But yes, a timeout will generate a `TaskCanceledException`, which is not intuitive at all. This will actually be changing in .NET Core at least ([just fixed last week](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40280)), but that doesn't help you.

Here is code I've used to rethrow a `TimeoutException` instead. The only *other* reason a `TaskCanceledException` could be thrown is if you passed a `CancellationToken` that ended up being cancelled, but you're not. So it's definitely a timeout.

```
} catch (TaskCanceledException) {
    //Could have been caused by cancellation or timeout if you used one.
    //If that was the case, rethrow.
    //cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    //HttpClient throws TaskCanceledException when the request times out. That's dumb.
    //Throw TimeoutException instead and say how long we waited.
    string time;
    if (_httpClient.Timeout.TotalHours > 1) {
        time = $"{_httpClient.Timeout.TotalHours:N1} hours";
    } else if (_httpClient.Timeout.TotalMinutes > 1) {
        time = $"{_httpClient.Timeout.TotalMinutes:N1} minutes";
    } else if (_httpClient.Timeout.TotalSeconds > 1) {
        time = $"{_httpClient.Timeout.TotalSeconds:N1} seconds";
    } else {
        time = $"{_httpClient.Timeout.TotalMilliseconds:N0} milliseconds";
    }
    throw new TimeoutException($"No response after waiting {time}.");
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that is due to 3rd party service?

Comment: The API you mean? Yes, that's why I mean. It is not returning a response. Your code is fine. It's possible that it either cannot keep up with you, or they have some kind of DDoS protection that is intentionally dropping your requests because you have sent too many. Ask them.

Comment: my async/await is OK, right? All this time I was trying to find bugs in my code with a reason :)

Comment: Yes, that looks fine. If you are getting responses sometimes then your code is fine.

Comment: since 3rd party did not response yet, should I also check my server which is in the cloud? I am not a server admin but if you can tell me what to check, I can try to do google engineering.

Comment: I checked the exception, IsCancellationRequested is True. Does this mean something wrong with my code? (somehow http client is disposed??) @Gabriel Luci

Comment: No, that's just what `HttpClient` does when the request times out.

Comment: since I am waiting for 3rd party reply, is there anywhere that I should check on my server? I mean just a precaution. @Gabriel Luci

Comment: The only thing you can do is not hit it so hard, and/or keep raising the timeout. The server is just not responding in time. You can't control that.

Comment: The load test is not hitting that hard I think. With Jmeter increasing users step by step. (starting from 25 users, holding for some seconds and increasing 25 users till 100 users at the same time) But since it is the test environment of 3rd party, maybe they can't handle the load.

Comment: the problem was `httpclient`. I changed it with `HTTPWebRequest` and all these errors gone.

Comment: I'd be curious to see your new code. On Windows, `HttpClient` just uses `HttpWebRequest` in the background anyway ([the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) says so), so I don't see how that could have fixed anything.

Comment: I added the HTTPWebRequest portion. Is there anything that I can improve?